# $n$ i.i.d. observations minus their sample mean yields $n-1$ i.i.d. observations?

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. and $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_n$.
Are $X_1-\bar{X},\dots,X_{n-1}-\bar{X}$ i.i.d.?

I know their degree of freedom is $n-1$, but is that true for their independence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

As a simple counterexample where we can check things explicitly, consider $n = 3$, $X_i \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(.5)$. Then we can build a table of the 8 possibilities, each of which is equally likely:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|cc}
X_1 & X_2 & X_3 & \bar X & X_1 - \bar X & X_2 - \bar X \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac13 & -\frac13 & -\frac13 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac13 & -\frac13 & \frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \frac23 & -\frac23 & \frac13 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac13 & \frac23 & -\frac13 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \frac23 & \frac13 & -\frac23 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & \frac23 & \frac13 & \frac13 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}

Note in particular that if $X_1 - \bar X = 0$ (which happens $\frac14$ of the time), so does $X_2 - \bar X$. Thus they can't be independent.